# My pagination is not working

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

Why my pagination is not working in another function it's working. It's show the link of pagination but the first page show all data another link of the page it's not show data.

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $page = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $param = new stdClass();
    if (!isset($page) || $page == '') {
        $page = 1;
    }
    $param->per_page = 5;
    $param->limit = ($page - 1) * $param->per_page;

    $paginate_url = site_url('warehouse');

    $data['total_result'] = $this->m_stock->count ($param);

    $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
    $config['num_links'] = 3;
    $config['base_url'] = $paginate_url;
    $config['total_rows'] = $data['total_result'];
    $config['per_page'] = $param->per_page;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination']   = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['item'] = $this->m_stock->get_item_code($param);
    $this->load->view('v_all_stocks', $data);
}
```

---

This function count database

```
function count(){
  $this->db->select("*");
  $this->db->from("tbl_item_code");
  $this->db->where('active', '1');
  $num_results = $this->db->count_all_results();
  return $num_results;
}
```

Comment: show the output you getting

Comment: it's show all data the result not separate page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY this :

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $page = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $param = new stdClass();
    if (!isset($page) || $page == '') {
        $page = 1;
    }
    $param->per_page = 5;
    $param->limit = ($page - 1) * $param->per_page;

    $paginate_url = site_url('warehouse');
    $results = $this->m_stock->get_item_code($param);  //get the db query object here
    $data['total_result'] =  $results->num_rows(); //get the number of results for this query

    $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;  //add this line if you wnat to use page numbers instead of offset in url
    $config['num_links'] = 3;
    $config['base_url'] = $paginate_url;
    $config['total_rows'] = $data['total_result'];
    $config['per_page'] = $param->per_page;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination']   = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['item'] = $results->result();  //get the results
    $this->load->view('v_all_stocks', $data);
}
```

In Your Model Code  :

```
function get_item_code($param){
    $result = array();
    $sql = "select ic.id, ic.item_code, ic.description, maxdt.maxdt, lc.balance ";
    $sql .= "from tbl_item_code ic ";
    $sql .= "left join ( tbl_lines_code lc inner join ( select id, max(dt) maxdt from tbl_lines_code group by id ) maxdt ";
    $sql .= "on lc.id = maxdt.id and lc.dt = maxdt.maxdt ) on ic.id = lc.id ";
    $sql .= "where ic.active = 1";
    if ($param->limit > 0)
        $this->db->limit($param->per_page, $param->limit);
    else 
        $this->db->limit($param->per_page);
     return $this->db->query($sql);  //change it to return the db query object

}
```

Comment: `$data['total_result'] = $this->m_stock->count ($param);`  What does this  Count function return ?

Comment: Yes, it's count data in database but i change  to $data['total_result'] = $this->m_stock->count ()   this function count http://stackoverflow.com/a/32647553/5243077

Comment: it's still can't working and show error in view page

Comment: it's working now but not separate data it's show 255 total data in one page